# A question about separating the variables: Integration

Tags: calculus, integration

My problem and question arises when we have something like $$\frac{dy}{dx}=y(1+x^2)$$
We can find the family of solutions to this simple differential equation by separating the variables, as I proceed ro demonstrate:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y(1+x^2)\implies \int\frac{1}{y}dy=\int(1+x^2)dx\implies \ln|y|=\frac{x^3}{3}+x+c$$
where $c$ is a constant. Now, from what I have seen in my textbooks, to the make the solution into the form $y=f(x)$ we make everything a power of $e$, as I have shown below:
$$y=e^{\frac{1}{3}x^3+x+c}=Ae^{\frac{1}{3}x^3+x}$$
But, isn't $\ln|y|$ equivalent to $\ln|-y|$, so shouldn't we have as the solution
$$y=\pm Ae^{\frac{1}{3}x^3+x}$$
I'm thinking that as $A$ is any constant the sign doesn't matter, but I'm not sure. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $A$ can be any constant in the final solution, but to make it more rigorous there are a few more considerations.

Firstly, you must observe that $y\equiv0$ is a solution to the initial differential equation.

In your working so far, you should have $A\gt0$, since you made the substitution $A=e^c$, and $e^c$ is always positive (exponential).

Then, when you raise $e$ to the power of both sides, you have
$$\color{red}{|y|}=Ae^{\frac{1}{3}x^3+x}$$
Now removing the absolute value,
$$y=\pm Ae^{\frac{1}{3}x^3+x}, \quad A\gt0$$
With $A\gt0$ since $A$ is still $e^c$, but the $\pm$ means that this now includes negative solutions.

Now, including the solution $y\equiv0$, the final answer is
$$y=Be^{\frac{1}{3}x^3+x}$$
for **any** arbitrary constant $B$, including $0$ and negative numbers.

Since you already have $A\gt0$, it is clearer if you define a new constant ($B$) which can be zero and negative instead of changing $A$ to now include zero in the final solution.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and logical explanation! I hadn't even realized that $A$ is necessarily positive, thanks for bringing that to my attention, and I like the suggestion of another constant, $B$. Overall an excellent answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the solution is sloppy. You should write $|y|=e^{\dots}$ and then observe that by changing the sign of $A$ you get both cases. However, it does not follow correctly here from the equation $y=e^{\dots}$, because then $A=e^c>0$.

(Typically, the initial condition will determine which "branch" of the solution you're needing.) Note that $y\equiv 0$ is also a solution of this equation, and that's taken care of by setting $A=0$.